# Exit from if block in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to exit from the below if block in Javascript. if I return, then it does not check for the next if condition. How do I do that?

```
if ($('#id1').length > 0) {

    if(yester_energy == "NaN" || yester_energy == 0){
      //break from #id1
    }

    else{
      //something
    }
    $("#abc").html(somthing)
}

if ($('#id2').length > 0) {

        if(yester_energy == "NaN" || yester_energy == 0){
          //break from #id2
        }

        else{
          //something
        }
}
```

Comment: You don't have to do anything special. The `else` blocks won't be executed if the `if` conditions are fulfilled.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add one line. Kindly see the updated question....Thanks. Apology

Answer (score 20):

Super late to the party, but for folks from search, you can use something called `labeling`. It's not good practice, but in rare cases that can be applied. Basically you can assign a name to the `if` statement that you want to break from. And anywhere in statement call `break` from specified name.

Code example:

```
my_if: if (condition) { 
    // do stuff
    break my_if;
    // not do stuff
}
```

in your particular case:

```
id1: if ($('#id1').length > 0) {
    if(yester_energy == "NaN" || yester_energy == 0){
        break id1;
    }else{
      //something
    }
    $("#abc").html(somthing)
}
```

More about `labeling` can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label#Syntax

Comment: Late answer for a late visitor. Thanks !

Comment: fantastic answer

Comment: Note that goto statements are generally not a good practice.

Comment: @ChrisP There is no goto statements. It's just the defining the block you want to leave.

Answer (score 6):

Even later to the party... Typically in such situations, I use a combination of `if` and `do...while` as follows...

```
if ( condition ) do {

  // processing

  if ( exit_condition ) break;

  // more processing...

} while ( false );
```

Thus, when the `break` is encountered, it applies to the `do...while` loop, and processing continues after the `while`, effectively breaking out of the outer `if` statement...

Answer (score 2):

All your code after `if(isNaN(yester_energy) || yester_energy == 0)` is in `else` block, so it'll not be executed if your data matches this `if`. And you just don't need anything else.

Also, if you want to check if variable got `NaN` value, then use `isNaN()` function. You can't just compare it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add one line. Kindly see the updated question....Thanks. Apology

Comment: @prafulbagai That changes nothing, just move this line to `else` block.

Comment: I did that before looking at your answer. THanks. Silly me

Answer (score 0):

Use switch statment,

```
   switch(n)
    {
    case 1:
      execute code block 1
      break;
    case 2:
      execute code block 2
      break;
    default:
      code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use function and pass command

```js
function iff(condition){
 if(condition ==0) return;
 console.log("other commands")
}


iff(0);
iff(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Don't Use Labeling

You can do labeling as the other answer suggests, but it smells odds and it will definitely come up in code review. It will confuse readers of your code and increase the maintenance burden of your codebase.

### Answer

Best is to refactor (extract out) the code inside the if-statement into a separate function that you can then `return` from. In addition to allowing you to exit from the code block early, it also makes your code more modular and readable.

### Example (based on OP)

```
if ($('#id1').length > 0) {
    ifInner(yester_energy)
    
    $("#abc").html(somthing) // [sic]
}

if ($('#id2').length > 0) {
    ifInner(yester_energy)
}

// Rename to something more descriptive.
function ifInner(yester_energy) {
    if (yester_energy == "NaN" || yester_energy == 0){
        // Break out.
        return;
    }
    else {
        // something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding another answer to the pool, in many cases using a try catch makes perfect sense:

```js
if(something is allowed) {
  try {
    if(missing requirements) throw 'missing requirements'
    //do your stuff;
  }
  catch {
    //you may do logging and issue warning here
  }
}
```